# Python Applications Failed to Redirect to Another Page

Tags: python, html, visual-studio, flask

I am trying to redirecting one page to another html page in python based on if and else statement . I have imported required library (****flask**,redirect**). I can access other Html page though the URL but When I tried to render the specific html page(CompleteAppliction.html) by clicking the button,  It is showing error  **Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.** I also used complete directory but did not work.

Here is the python code.

```
import flask
import pickle
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from flask import Flask,redirect

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler


#load models at top of app to load into memory only one time
with open('models/loan_application_model_lr.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    clf_lr = pickle.load(f)


# with open('models/knn_regression.pkl', 'rb') as f:
#     knn = pickle.load(f)    
ss = StandardScaler()


genders_to_int = {'MALE':1,
                  'FEMALE':0}

married_to_int = {'YES':1,
                  'NO':0}

education_to_int = {'GRADUATED':1,
                  'NOT GRADUATED':0}

dependents_to_int = {'0':0,
                      '1':1,
                      '2':2,
                      '3+':3}

self_employment_to_int = {'YES':1,
                          'NO':0}                      

property_area_to_int = {'RURAL':0,
                        'SEMIRURAL':1, 
                        'URBAN':2}




app = flask.Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')
@app.route('/')
def main():
    return (flask.render_template('index.html'))

@app.route('/report')
def report():
    return (flask.render_template('report.html'))

@app.route('/jointreport')
def jointreport():
    return (flask.render_template('jointreport.html'))

@app.route('/CompleteApplication')
def CompleteApplication():
    return (flask.render_template('CompleteApplication.html'))

@app.route("/Loan_Application1", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def Loan_Application1():
    
    if flask.request.method == 'GET':
        return (flask.render_template('Loan_Application1.html'))
    
    if flask.request.method =='POST':
        
        #get input
        #gender as string
        genders_type = flask.request.form['genders_type']
        #marriage status as boolean YES: 1 , NO: 0
        marital_status = flask.request.form['marital_status']
        #Dependents: No. of people dependent on the applicant (0,1,2,3+)
        dependents = flask.request.form['dependents']
        
        #dependents = dependents_to_int[dependents.upper()]
        
        #education status as boolean Graduated, Not graduated.
        education_status = flask.request.form['education_status']
        #Self_Employed: If the applicant is self-employed or not (Yes, No)
        self_employment = flask.request.form['self_employment']
        #Applicant Income
        applicantIncome = float(flask.request.form['applicantIncome'])
        #Co-Applicant Income
        coapplicantIncome = float(flask.request.form['coapplicantIncome'])
        #loan amount as integer
        loan_amnt = float(flask.request.form['loan_amnt'])
        #term as integer: from 10 to 365 days...
        term_d = int(flask.request.form['term_d'])
        # credit_history
        credit_history = int(flask.request.form['credit_history'])
        # property are
        property_area = flask.request.form['property_area']
        #property_area = property_area_to_int[property_area.upper()]

        #create original output dict
        output_dict= dict()
        output_dict['Applicant Income'] = applicantIncome
        output_dict['Co-Applicant Income'] = coapplicantIncome
        output_dict['Loan Amount'] = loan_amnt
        output_dict['Loan Amount Term']=term_d
        output_dict['Credit History'] = credit_history
        output_dict['Gender'] = genders_type
        output_dict['Marital Status'] = marital_status
        output_dict['Education Level'] = education_status
        output_dict['No of Dependents'] = dependents
        output_dict['Self Employment'] = self_employment
        output_dict['Property Area'] = property_area
        


        x = np.zeros(21)
    
        x[0] = applicantIncome
        x[1] = coapplicantIncome
        x[2] = loan_amnt
        x[3] = term_d
        x[4] = credit_history

        print('------this is array data to predict-------')
        print('X = '+str(x))
        print('------------------------------------------')

        pred = clf_lr.predict([x])[0]
        
        if pred==1:
            res = 'Congratulations! your Loan Application has been Approved!'
            # return redirect (flask.render_template('Loan_Application1.html')
            return redirect(flask.render_template('CompleteApplication.html'))
        else:
                res = 'Unfortunatly your Loan Application has been Denied'
        #Stay in same page 

 
        #render form again and add prediction
        return flask.render_template('Loan_Application1.html', 
                                     original_input=output_dict,
                                     result=res,)
     
        
      
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is the screen shot of the project structure.

[image]

Here is the screenshot when the page is loaded first time and works fine.
[image]

Here is the screen shot when I clicked the button .
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```py
return redirect(flask.render_template('CompleteApplication.html'))
```

to

```py
return flask.render_template('CompleteApplication.html')
```

`redirect()` is for URLs, e.g. `return redirect('https://stackoverflow.com')`